# How do I pass one ID from a view which has a Model Type of IEnumerable to aPartial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I am trying to select the restaurant Id of the logged on user and pass it to a partial view to display a list of reservations for that user.

I currently have

```
 @model IEnumerable<RestaurantApplication.Models.Restaurant>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}
@if (ViewBag.IsRestaurant == true)
{
<h2>You are logged in a restaurant user</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New Restaurant", "CreateRestaurant", null, new { 
@class = "btn btn-success" })
</p>

 @Html.Action("RestaurantReservationsPartialView", new { id = 1  })
```

Here I want to replace the id = 1 with the id of the current restaurant

My code displays a list of the users restaurants

```
if (Model.Count() != 0)
{
    <h1>Your Current Restaurants</h1>
    <table id="restaurantOwnerTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Restaurant Name</th>
                <th>County</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Options</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RestaurantName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.County)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RestaurantType)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.RestaurantID }) |
                        @*@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.RestaurantID }) |*@
                        @Html.ActionLink("View Reservations", "ViewReservations", new { id = item.RestaurantID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("View ReservationsToday", "ViewReservationsToday", new { id = item.RestaurantID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.RestaurantID })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>


}
        else
        {
            @Html.Label("You do not have any Restaurants , consider making one?")
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are passing a list of restaurants to the view. where is your loop code ?

Comment: After adding the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the child action in the loop where you loop all the restaurants and use the RestaurnatID property of each item in the loop iterations.

For example,

```
@model IEnumerable<RestaurantApplication.Models.Restaurant>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
       <td>
         @Html.Action("RestaurantReservationsPartialView", new { id = item.RestaurantID})
      </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shyju this retrieves the correct data but never stops loading the page

Comment: I am not sure why it does because i do not have full visibility to your code. I suggest trying to narrow it down and see where it is taking much time. You might also consider  eager loading restaurant reservation in the main action method using joins ( so there will be only one database hit).

Comment: Seems to be running fine now and retrieving the data I wanted. Thanks for your help